# Comma seperated tags search from the data attribute

Tags: jquery, filter

I have a search field where i am entering the tags (multile tag comma seperated)

I would like to find the each tag in the div data attribute if found then show that div otherwise hide it.

HTML CODE

```
<div class="profile-listing">


<div data-tag="a b" class="profile"></div>


<div data-tag="b c" class="profile"></div>


<div data-tag="a c" class="profile"></div>


<div data-tag="d c" class="profile"></div>

</div>

jQuery("#search_tag").keyup(function(){


var string_filter = jQuery(this).val();
var array_filter = string_filter.split(',');
var filter = jQuery(this).val(), count = 0;

jQuery(".profile_listing .profile").each(function(){

   jQuery.each( array_filter, function( intValue, currentFilter ) {
        if(jQuery(".profile").indexOf(currentFilter) >-1){jQuery(this).show(); }else{ 
        jQuery(this).hide();
    }

    });

});
```

});

Case:

If i enter in search field "a" so div that contain data-tag value "a" should show like profile div (1,3) and if i enter a,b then div number (1,2,3) should show.

Any jquery filter help.

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Because the site is not a free coding service, you are supposed to provide an attempt to solve the problem yourself (in the question itself, not as a comment), and ask a specific question about what doesn't work. Good luck!

Comment: Also, please have a read of [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the dom elements to achieve this.

Concepts used in this are

**For - each loop**  more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript)

**string comparison** more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

**JavaScript Split** more on this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```js
// this is your input 
var input = 'a,b';

// Split the input by comma
var profileSplit = input.split(',');

// iterate through all div which has class 'profile'
$('.profile').each(function(i, obj) {
  
  // hide the objects by default
  $(obj).hide();
  
  // retrive the data-tag value
  var tagVal = $(obj).data('tag');
  
  // iterate through your 'input' which as split by , earlier
  profileSplit.forEach(function(item) {
    //check if 'data-tag' value  with the input
    if (tagVal.indexOf(item) >= 0) {
      // show the div. 'obj' is the reference to the current div iteration
      $(obj).show();
      
      console.log(tagVal)
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="profile-listing">


  <div data-tag="a b" class="profile">one</div>


  <div data-tag="b c" class="profile">two </div>


  <div data-tag="a c" class="profile">three</div>


  <div data-tag="d c" class="profile">four</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Nicely explained, but doesn't quite match OPs requirements - need to change to `if (tagVal.indexOf(item) >= 0) {`

Comment: Thanks a lot guys